# How can I implement multithreading in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, multithreading

I am now using the node.js for scraping the contents of pages.
Using axios module to fetch contents for over 10,000 pages, I would like to use multithreading for many pages scraping.

Comment: I think there are many solutions other than nodejs for parallel processing. Its not meant for that. Your best bet is to use some sort of background processing with asynchronous programing.  But if you insist on working with threads, use `worker_threads` module which would work with Node.js v10.5.0 or higher.

Comment: In nodejs, you have asynchronous I/O which makes it really efficient for multiple networking operations in flight at once without using threads.  You also have [Worker Threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) and you have [child processes](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) for operations that use more CPU.  As we don't really write this type of code for you here, the ball is really in your court to try one of these options and ask a more specific question about your implementation.